# Chrome is downloading file in iframe instead of displaying it

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, iframe, video

I'm trying to make a video file run inside an iframe in all the browsers but Chrome and IE works kind of awkward.

This is my iframe, pretty simple:

```
<iframe src="url-to-file" frameborder="0" height="150" width="300"></iframe>
```

When I refresh the page, the wmv video file gets downloaded instead of running inside the iframe, is there a way to make it work?

Internet Explorer 11 is opening a new window with the video file.

(By the way, I can't use `<video></video>` because my site doesn't support HTML5)

Comment: What format is the video file?

Comment: .wmv (Windows Media Video), but it happens with other formats too. The only one that works is the mp4. (for videos)